# Bean creation  is failing (spring)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a bean and than trying to inject the same in my Controller but i am getting bean creation failure error.Here is my code

```
@Service("springSecurityLoginServiceImpl")
public class SpringSecurityLoginServiceImpl implements SpringSecurityLoginService
{
  //impl
}
```

this is how i am trying to inject it in my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("springSecurity/login.json")
public class SpringSecurityLoginController
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("springSecurityLoginServiceImpl")
    SpringSecurityLoginService springSecurityLoginService;

}
```

There is no entry in Spring-MVC-config xml file except these annotation, but when i am starting server facing the following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0'
 defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-mvc-config.xml]: 
 Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityLoginController': 
 Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Could not autowire field: com.core.servicelayer.user.SpringSecurityLoginService com.storefront.controllers.pages.SpringSecurityLoginController.springSecurityLoginService; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
 No matching bean of type [com.core.servicelayer.user.SpringSecurityLoginService] found for dependency: 
 expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
 Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
 @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=springSecurityLoginServiceImpl)}
```

i am not sure what i am doing wrong or what extra i have to do

Comment: Can you show the component-scan tag that you are using in spring-mvc-config.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpringSecurityLoginController` class refers `SpringSecurityLoginService` class, for which a bean isn't defined. That much the error says.

It is true, because you've only defined a bean for the class `LoginServiceImpl`, which doesn't seem to extend `SpringSecurityLoginService` in any way.

Spring's bean lookup algorithm first searches for beans of which type is, or extends, `SpringSecurityLoginService`. Then, it narrows the avaialble options using the `Qualifier`. In this case, no bean is found in the first place...

See [Spring doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch04s11.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers):

> **4.11.3 Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers**
>
> Since autowiring by type may lead to multiple candidates, it is often
>   necessary to have more control over the selection process. One way to
>   accomplish this is with Spring's @Qualifier annotation. This allows
>   for associating qualifier values with specific arguments, narrowing
>   the set of type matches so that a specific bean is chosen for each
>   argument.

You need that `LoginServiceImpl` will implement `SpringSecurityLoginService`, for instance.

**EDIT**

Since it was just a typo you might be not including `SpringSecurityLoginService`'s package in `component-scan` tag, in your spring configuration file (as gkamal has already mentioned). You should have there something like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

where `org.example` should be replaced by `SpringSecurityLoginService`'s package.

Comment: my mistake as i just done some typo in my post.Please see updated post as `SpringSecurityLoginService` being implemented by `SpringSecurityLoginServiceImpl`